# What exactly does the "DOES>" word do?

Tags: forth, gforth

I was messing around and trying to understand it, so I wrote a simple word to test it:

```
: test ." compile time" DOES> ." runtime" ;
```

The problem is, this word doesn't behave in a consistent way at all. Its output seems to vary depending on a number of factors, like:

- is this the first line to be interpreted?
- are there other words defined after it?

Also, sometimes it doesn't print anything at all.

(Using Gforth)

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339283/forth-how-do-create-and-does-work-exactly

Comment: That answer says `I'm leaning on the spec. that says "An ambiguous condition exists if [ the most recent definition ] was not defined with CREATE ..."  so since you don't use CREATE it won't work the way you expect.

Comment: Here's that "ambiguous condition" working in the spec: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/ansforth-cvs/documents/html3/core/DOES.html

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That same spec says it's "typical use" is within a colon definiton aswell, so this just continues to confuse me.

Comment: So, I am not an expert in FORTH so I can't tell you how it does work, but it seems to need to be used in a colon definition to modify the definition of a word created by CREATE.  Since your example doesn't use CREATE to make a word before using DOES>, your DOES> is modifying the most recently created word instead which is giving you surprising results.

Comment: For an introduction, I would recommend reading chapter 11 of *Starting Forth*, *[Extending the Compiler](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/11-forth-compiler-defining-words/)*.

Answer (score 4):

This is your code:

```
: test ." compile time" DOES> ." runtime" ;
```

After entering that, I can use your word *without* the ambiguous behavior you are encountering:

```
CREATE def 12345 , test \ prints "compile time"
```

It prints `compile time`, because that's the behavior you compiled into `test` before `DOES>`.
*Note: this is not actually running at compile time.*

`DOES>` ends the definition of the word, but changes it so `test` also modifies the last defined word so that it puts its data field address on the stack, and then runs the behaviour found after `DOES>`.

Using the word I created, it has the instantiated behavior you defined, following the implicit behaviour of pushing the address:

```
def @ . \ prints runtime 12345
```

*Forth 2012 note: Per the definition of `DOES>` in Forth 2012, this would cause ambiguous behavior if the last word was not defined with `CREATE`. However, Gforth allows any word definition to be modified.*

I hope this example helps explain why, usually, `CREATE` is used within the definition that uses `DOES>`, but it is certainly not required.

Answer (score 3):

### Interactive play

In Gforth you can play with `does>` interpretively.

```
create foo 123 ,

foo @ . \ prints 123

does> ( addr -- ) @ . ;

foo \ prints 123

does> ( addr -- ) @ 1+ . ;

foo \ prints 124

' foo >body @ . \ prints 123
```

So `does>` just changes behavior of the last word, when this last word is defined via `create`. It's a mistake if you run `does>` when the last word was not defined via `create`.

### Usage in practice

Usually `does>` is used to set a new behavior only once for a word defined via `create`. An ability to alter this behavior several times it just a side effect of historical implementation, and this effect is almost not used in the practice.

---

### Alternative ways

In practice, the cases when `does>` is used, can be also implemented without `does>`.

For example, let we want to implement a word `counter` that creates a counter that every time returns the next value, and that is used in the following way:

```
1 counter x1
x1 . \ prints 1
x1 . \ prints 2
x1 . \ prints 3
```

An implementation via `create` `does>`

```
: counter ( x0 "ccc" -- ) \ Run-Time: ( -- x )
  create ,  does> ( addr -- x ) dup >r @ dup 1+ r> !
;
```

An implementation using a [quotation](https://gforth.org/manual/Quotations.html)

```
[undefined] lit, [if] : lit, ( x  -- ) postpone lit, ; [then]
[undefined] xt,  [if] : xt,  ( xt -- ) compile, ;      [then]

: counter ( x0 "ccc" -- ) \ Run-Time: ( -- x )
  align here >r , [: ( addr -- x ) dup >r @ dup 1+ r> ! ;] >r
  :  r> r> lit, xt, postpone ;
;
```

An implementation using a macro (code inlining) via the [word](https://gforth.org/manual/Macros.html) `]]`:

```
: counter ( x0 "ccc" -- ) \ Run-Time: ( -- x )
  align here >r , 
  :  r> lit, ]] dup >r @ dup 1+ r> ! [[ postpone ; 
;
```

Answer (score 3):

[ruvim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919966/what-exactly-does-the-does-word-do/64930256#64930256) may be easier to understand in Gforth.

The code below defines a 'classic' defining word that creates variables initialised to the item on the stack at compile time. I hope the tracing statements in the definitions will help show what is happening

```
: var    \ create: n <name> -- ; does>: -- addr ; initialised VARIABLE
  create      \ create a dictionary item for <name>.
  ." HERE at compile time: " HERE .
  ,           \ place n at HERE in the dictionary
  does>       \ Push the HERE as at compile time to the stack
  ." Run time address on the stack:" dup .
;
```

`var` can now be used to define new words that have the run time action defined after DOES>.

```
10 var init10    \ Use var to define a new word init10
\ HERE at compile time: 135007328

init10 CR DUP . @ .
\ Run time address on the stack:135007328
\ 135007328 10   \ addr of init10, content of that address.

12 var init12    \ Use var to define a new word init12
\ HERE at compile time: 135007376

init12 CR DUP . @ .
\ Run time address on the stack:135007376
\ 135007376 12

100 init10 !    \ Store 100 in init10
\ Run time address on the stack:135007328
init10 @ .
\ Run time address on the stack:135007328  100
\ init10 now contains 100
```

Hopefully the answers will provide a framework to explore defining words and the action of DOES>.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't create and does> very similar to logic happening in a class constructor, and logic happening for an invokable object (calling an object like a function)?

Comment: There is a similarity.  The code between `CREATE` and `DOES>` initialises an instance of the 'object'.  The code after `DOES>` runs the only method for the 'object'.  There will only be one `DOES>` action.  Using the address of the 'object' as one of the parameters.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt To get more oop style behaviour the defining word reserves the memory and initialises it and creates a word that returns the base address.  Then a series of words can be defined that use these addresses.  There are also various oop packages defined in Forth which wrap this behaviour into their own syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A word that define words that allocate memory can be equipped with an action thru DOES> which gives the address to the memory block.

A simple example is CONSTANT wich can be defined as

: CONSTANT ( n -- )  CREATE , DOES> @ ;